# как прописать exclude в xcopy?

Tags: cmd, bat

```
C:\Users\qwert>xcopy "C:/neGit" "C:/neGit/4test" /E /H /exclude:"C:/neGit/storage"
Не удается прочесть файл: "C:/neGit/storage"
```

у меня пара вопросов по этой команде

во-первых, я хочу скопировать все кроме папки `storage`(и ее содержимого), как это сделать?

во-вторых, как мне скопировать все кроме нескольких папок/файлов, к примеру `storage` и `test.txt`, как это сделать?

p.s. `C:/neGit/storage` существует

Comment: а что вам говорит `xcopy /?` ? вы ведь правда уже посмотрели справку как работать с `xcopy` перед тем как задать этот вопрос?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, в инфе об `xcopy` написано что то такое `/exclude:file1[+file2]`, но я не могу понять что писать надо, никаких примеров кода в нете не нашел(

  мне просто пример бы глянуть...

Comment: Там написано и как именно его "готовить": `/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
               Список файлов, содержащих строки.  Каждая строка должна располагаться в отдельной строке в файлах. Если какая-либо из строк совпадает с любой частью абсолютного пути к копируемому файлу, такой файл исключается из операции копирования.  Например, при указании строки \obj\ или .obj будут исключены все файлы из каталога obj или все файлы с расширением OBJ соответственно.`

Comment: **Список файлов, содержащих строки.** туда передается ИМЯ ФАЙЛА, в котором записаны все исключения. т.е. создаете файл (exclude.txt) на каждой строке файла пишите фильтр который что либо исключает, в exclude подставяете это имя( exclude.txt)